# db2 z/os transform simple query in dynamic query

Tags: sql, dynamic, db2, zos, dbvisualizer

I want to transform a simple query in a dynamic query, passing some variables directly.
The query could be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mySchema.THETABLE a 
WHERE a.THECOLUMN = 'someVariable';
```

So, I tried something like this:

```
DECLARE v_schema varchar(7);
DECLARE v_param1 varchar(200);
DECLARE v_sqlstr varchar(2000);

SET v_schema = 'mySchema';
SET v_param1 = 'someVariable';

SET v_sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM ' 
   || v_schema 
   || '.THETABLE a WHERE a.THECOLUMN = ''' 
   || v_param1 
   || ''';

execute sql v_sqlstr;
```

How can this be done?
When I try this type of code in the dbvisualizer commander window, I get back the error:

```
[DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  
[Error Code: -199, SQL State: 42601]  
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=VARCHAR;
TABLE STATEMENT , . SCROLL INSENSITIVE SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE NO, DRIVER=4.15.82
```

Comment: try to print the output of your `v_sqlstr` before the line `execute sql v_sqlstr;` so that we can see what is happening

Comment: But the error seems to be something regarding the "DECLARE".
I think I miss something about the syntax of this block...
I'm a newbie with z/os...

Comment: `SQLERRMC=VARCHAR` means it's complaining about the `varchar` bit, it expects one of the keywords on the final line of the error. Is this within a `begin/end`?

Comment: I tried putting `BEGIN/END`, `BEGIN ATOMIC/END`... When I add the BEGIN, it gives me this error:  `[BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CODICEBANCA;SECTION, DRIVER=4.15.82
[DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -199, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=VARCHAR;TABLE STATEMENT , . SCROLL INSENSITIVE SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE NO, DRIVER=4.15.82`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
   v_schema varchar(7);
   v_param1 varchar(200);
   v_sqlstr varchar(2000);
BEGIN

  v_schema := 'mySchema';
  v_param1 := 'someVariable';

SET v_sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM ' 
   || v_schema 
   || '.THETABLE a WHERE a.THECOLUMN = ''' 
   || v_param1 
   || ''';

execute sql v_sqlstr;
END;
```

More detailed examples of Begin/End code blocks in [the link here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0908anonymousblocks/index.html?ca=dat)

Answer (score 0):

DbVisualizer use semicolon as a statement separator. When executing a block of code that includes semicolon as part of the code you need to pay attention. If the editor contains only the block of code, easiest is to run with **SQL Commander->Execute Buffer** as that will pass the complete script to the DB and run it without any parsing.

There are several solutions and you find them here:

http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG91/Executing+Complex+Statements

Comment: Thank you Roger, I supposed it should be something like that.
Now I have to understand the correct syntax...